# Swift variant of (FB)KVOController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, kvocontroller

I'd like to attempt to migrate/reimplement my app to Swift. I've done some tutorials and examples and want to try a "real" app now. My current app uses the `KVOController` cocoapod quite a bit though. So I'm looking for something (preferably as a pod) that could be a replacement in my Swift implementation. Are there any yet? Something that was as semantically similar to KVOController as possible would be preferrable.

Comment: Why not just use KVOController? I mean, it will work with Swift.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the whole "mixing" thing. For example, I use AFNetworking pod also. But I figured I'd switch to AlamoFire (the swift version). Just seemed like I'd have to worry less about objc-swift bridging that way.